# Using swagger in all areas of help-files

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

We use swagger for our .net web api documentation but we also need to provide help for our general software.... user guides etc.

Can anyone recommend a way of doing this or an alternative like swagger for general help files? (everything i have seen looks really dated)